# ELK Stack Log timestamp

Tags: elastic-stack

I'm relatively new to ELK stack in general and I'm trying to process some old logs back from 2014 for visualization. I was wondering if there's a way to allow Kibana to display the same time stamp as the creation of the logs instead of the time stamp when I added them into my forwarder client.

This is an excerpt from my filter section

[image: filter]

Comment: Aren't you missing an underscore in your `date` filter, i.e. `syslog timestamp` should be `syslog_timestamp`?

Comment: Hi Val, I've tried using your suggestion and the results remain the same. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp it's only show the time when logstash take the logs and saved to elasticsearch. Logstash can't know when that's logs had been created. The only possible  way to know that , it's maybe if you saved the time inside the log's if they are systemlogs or your own logs with timestamps inside. Then you can create a filter in logstash and then just used as a key.

You can use grok filter for that.

http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match

Example:

Output log

```
55.3.244.1 GET /index.html 15824 0.043
```

Filter

```
%{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:duration}
```

Logstash config

```
input {
      file {
        path => "/var/log/http.log"
      }
    }
    filter {
      grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:duration}" }
      }
    }
```